# Access 2007 Textbox Date Formatting

Tags: ms-access, date, formatting

I converted an older Access app to 2007, and now the date formatting in editable textboxes is not working. The format I'm using is **mm/dd/yy**, but the date is displaying with a 4-digit year.

I've tried other formats just for testing, eg **mmm/d/yy** - they display correctly *except* for the year which insists on being 4 digits.

This appears to be a new 'wrinkle' in A2007 - has anyone found a way around this?

Comment: Why would anyone not want 4-digit years? Did we learn nothing at all from the Y2K debacle?

Comment: David, I appreciate what you're saying, but whilst the user enters 4-digit years, it takes a lot of extra display space, hence the 2-digit display.

Comment: Unless I had a form with a lot of date columns, I'd suck it up and display 4-digit years, and take the space away from one of the other columns on the form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see something different on my system.  With an ACCDB format database and a textbox format set to mm/dd/yy, today's date displays as 10/03/10.

It appears that if the checkbox for "Use four-digit year formatting" for "This database" is checked, Access uses 4 digits for the year regardless of the control's format property.  To find that setting, click the Office Button, then Access Options -> Advanced and scroll down to the General heading.

Comment: Thanks, you're right, if that option is set, it does override control formatting. I unchecked it, and found that I can still set formatting to 4-digit years when I want to - so now I have the choice between 2 and 4 digit year displays again!